# Python Pandas For loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, apply

I am trying to create a column, in my dataframe, which will calculate values on behalf of certain categories in another column.

Lets say, I have a column X, which has materials of different types, and there is a price of each of the types. Now, I want to append a column, based on each group along with Materials column, stating the Median of that particular type of materials.

Columns would be like Materials|Prices| Median_Prices

Help me in generating Column Median Prices.

```
Material,Prices,Median _Prices
a,12,12.5 
a,13,12.5
b,34,34
b,565,34
b,8,34
c,87,66
c,66,66
c,7,66
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for loops to do this.  Let use `groupby` and `transform`:

```
df['Median_Prices_Calc'] = df.groupby('Material')['Prices'].transform('median')
```

Output:

```
  Material  Prices  Median_Prices  Median_Prices_Calc
0        a      12           12.5                12.5
1        a      13           12.5                12.5
2        b      34           34.0                34.0
3        b     565           34.0                34.0
4        b       8           34.0                34.0
5        c      87           66.0                66.0
6        c      66           66.0                66.0
7        c       7           66.0                66.0
```